# Running mame on Linux

Tags: linux, games

I tried to install `mame` on Linux, and the icons appear inside the game folder (`xmame`, `xmame.sdl`, `xmame.x11`) but none of them would run. What is the problem?

---

**Edit**: It says they are read-only, but I cannot change permissions, it says, because I am not the owner. So what should I do? Run sudo command?

Comment: Try running the game's binary from command line (terminal) and observe any errors in output.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause (and the simplest to rectify) is that the xmame file doesn't have it's executable bit set, so check that the permissions include an x for you or your group.

Other issues will require more detail from you. You should update the question with symptoms as 'would not run' could cover a multitude of sins.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to install XMAME, I learnt a lesson if you need xmame please install a  front end highly configurable please try to install KXMAME (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxmame/) and you can take all control for XMAME.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should run `sudo` to change the permissions, but don't try to run the app because it could be insecure:

In order to change the owner you should run in a root shell:

> `#chown -R [user] ./fileordirectory`

In order to add exexution permision you should run in a root shell:

> `#chmod +x ./file`

---

**Edit**: You said:

> "and the icons appear inside the game
>   folder"

Are you clicking on the icons? That could be the problem -- you should click on the executable files, which normally don't have icons in Linux. If that doesn't work, you should try to set the executable permissions.